What close vote is appropriate on a question that arose out of a mistaken understanding?
I'm talking in relation to my SO post here.
I did not understand the library properly and assumed some things based on appearances. The one-line answer to that question is "What I say cannot be done in fact CAN be".
Should this be closed off as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" (my close vote) or as "needs details or clarity" (the other close vote)? Moreover, as it has been longer than a day, should I instead flag it for mod intervention as it probably won't reach enough views to garner 4 close votes (or should I just simply delete the post)?

EDIT: the question is closed

Why not just delete it instead? That'll be its ultimate fate when the Roomba gets to it anyway. That said, IMO the important part of the not reproducible/typo close reason is the "less likely to help future readers" part, unless it's a misconception that other people are likely to have.

I tried deleting it. It appears that the question has 1 UV and 1 DV and if I delete it, my rep remains as if it weren't deleted (+8). That doesn't seem right...

@kesarlingHe-Him Sometimes it takes time for rep to get recalculated. In any case, I'm not sure why that would prevent you from deleting it.

@kesarlingHe-Him - Reputation when it’s recalculated once a day would result in no reputation being earned or gained.

What would the value of such a question/answer pair be for the site? I don't see any value for future visitors.

@M-- I think that requires a bit too much of an inductive leap, and there are other things that OP should know besides the correct close reason for the question.

IMO, the situation here is fairly straightforward, but there are a lot of details worth pointing out.

If you are planning to ask a question along the lines of "how do I deal with the fact that [obvious approach to my problem] won't work?", please be very sure that it indeed won't work before asking. The best way to make sure is to try it. If it indeed doesn't work, then you have a choice: ask why it doesn't work; or forget your attempt altogether and just ask how to do whatever it is. (In this case you can consider mentioning that you know the obvious approach doesn't work; but try to avoid anything that would encourage people to get sidetracked by the "why" question.)

For a question like this, "Not reproducible or caused by a typo" is indeed the appropriate closure reason. As you discovered, there is no problem; if there is no problem at all, then there is definitely not a reproducible problem.

In cases like this, arguably the right thing to do is to delete the question yourself - since it fundamentally cannot be improved. Unfortunately, this may have negative consequences because of the automated question-ban algorithm, which we (including moderators) cannot control. (That's why the first point is so important.)

The close reason of "Needs details or clarity" also makes sense, since you don't clearly explain what you mean by "this restraint" (it should probably say "this constraint", BTW). A high-quality question will use words to explain "what I want to do", not just code. However, this is a relatively minor problem here.

It takes only 3 votes nowadays to close a question, not 5.

Unless someone edits the question, upvotes it to +1 or higher, or casts a reopen vote, it will automatically be deleted by the system after 9 days. So there is no pressing need to clean things up manually.

Please do not flag moderators for this. There are only a couple dozen or so of them for millions of total users and thousands of new posts per day, not to mention the work of cleaning up existing Q&A. There is nothing to do here that requires moderator privileges; therefore they should not be bothered about it, and will certainly reject any flags raised about it.



"So there is no pressing need to clean things up manually." - I was wondering why this answer did not have the usual bucket of upvotes. This may explain it, it contains a culture shock :)

@Gimby I generally consider closure to be far more important than deletion, given the fact that I'll probably never get my way on "questions start closed" (it requires too much other infrastructure to work properly). Time spent manually trying to get things deleted is time that could be spent combatting the FGITWs.
